# setInterval change background div

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have code

```
  function smena(){     
     $('.wrapper').animate({opacity:0},2500,function(){
           setTimeout ($('.wrapper').animate({opacity:1},2500),5000)
      });
   }
   $(document).ready(function(){

       setInterval('smena();',10000);   
  });
```

why me animaation jump? i want just change bg for my div "wrapper".

Comment: What do you mean by "animation jump"? What happens when you run the code, and how does that differ from what you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you're not passing the functions around correctly for setTimeout.  You're actually passing the result of "$('.wrapper').animate({opacity:1},2500)" to the setTimeout, not the action itself.  This is probably what you want:

```
  function smena(){     
     $('.wrapper').animate({opacity:0},2500,function(){
           setTimeout (function() {
             $('.wrapper').animate({opacity:1},2500)
           },5000)
      });
  }
  $(document).ready(function() {
       setInterval(smena, 10000);   
  });
```